# A tag visual-basic é referente a VB.NET ou VB6?

Tags: debate, status-pronto, tags, tag-específica

Vi há pouco uma pergunta sobre VB.NET que tinha a tag [visual-basic](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-basic), logo eu removi a tag, mas depois vi que esta tag não está marcada como sinônimo de [vb.net](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb.net) nem [vb6](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb6).

Também é importante dizer que esta tag só tem uma pergunta (que é de VB.NET).

Deveríamos excluir esta tag ou marcá-la como sinônimo de uma das outras duas?

Comment: Eu diria para tirar a tag dessa pergunta e o sistema faz o resto ;)

Comment: Estas *tags* são das mais mal utilizadas. Pra mim vb, vb6 e visual-basic é tudo a mesma coisa e normalmente nada tem a ver com vb.net (que muitas usam as *tags* vb + .net, o que é um duplo erro.

Comment: Então seria o caso de marcamos as três primeiras como sinônimos e escrevermos na recomendação de uso para não confundi-las com `vb.net`. Não?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Criei os sinônimos.

As tags [vb](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb), [vb6](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb6) e [visual-basic](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-basic) serão remapeadas para [visual-basic-6](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-basic-6).